# jQuery - wait for an element to show up within an iFrame and grab its value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Suppose upon an event an iframe opens. (no cross site, the iframe is part of the DOM).

So when the iframe opens it displays for example to select a file.

[image]

The second state of the iFrame upon selecting the file would be displaying information about the media uploaded as well as its title. Ex below after the file is selected.

[image]

My question is suppose I wanted to grab the value of 'Title' using JS. How would I go on doing this?

```
$('.addmediabutton').click(function() {

         $('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'iframe', function(e) {
           //How do I wait for eg. class = "title" to show up and grab its value? 

 });
});
```

Would I have to use a [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) above to track a given added node or element or is there an easier way.

If you need any further clarification please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reaching the second state after an ajax call it'll be as easy as including the feature in the on success section of the ajax request.